# curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 892)

Tags: curl

on running command 
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle" : getting error

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:54 --:--:--    0
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle: No such file or
Warning: directory
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:55 --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 892)
```

I have installed the curl and set up the path.

Comment: "Failed writing body" means that curl got an error when it tried to write (the first ?) 8192 bytes. Out of disk? No rights to write there?

Comment: I have right to write there and what do u mean  by out of disk?

Comment: I meant anything what would cause `fwrite()` to return a failure.

Comment: out of disk for me